# How to fix URL rewrites massively via SQL?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, sql

I had migrated my store from Magento 1 and I'm having many URLs that contain **.html.html** in the final of the string.

I want to update all my 88187 URL rewrites, replacing **.html.html** to **.html**

I already checked my URL suffix and prefix, and the product and category URLs registered in the admin panel.

[image: Magento2 URL rewrite]

How could I do that via SQL in the **url_rewrite** table?

Answer (score 1):

To fix it I ran this SQL query below.

```sql
SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `request_path` LIKE '%html.html' AND `redirect_type` LIKE '0';

UPDATE `url_rewrite` SET request_path = REPLACE(request_path, '.html.html', '.html') WHERE `request_path` LIKE ('%html.html') AND `redirect_type` LIKE '0';
```

Or you can install the Elgento module and run its commands as bellow.

```
composer require elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls
php bin/magento module:enable Iazel_RegenProductUrl
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento repair:url
```

Comment: Also,Please check Your URL suffix is `.html.html ` or `.html`, if its is `.html.html ` then changes it at core_config_data table